# Why does having a list inside of a list give me list indices error?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures

Hey So I am new to Data Structures and wanted to try out 2D array in Pandas and am getting a error in the following code

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime as dt

ls = [[dt(2021, 9, 4).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "WTM", 62, 100, 64, 100, 86, 100, 212, 300], [dt(2021, 9, 5).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "WTA", 48, 60, 39, 60, 31, 60, 118, 180]
    [dt(2021, 10, 23).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "WTM", 7, 100, 27, 100, 47, 100, 81, 300]]

data = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=['Exam Date', 'Exam Type', 'Maths', 'Max Marks', 'Chemistry', 'Max Marks', 'Physics', 'Max Marks', 'Total', 'Max Marks'])
```

The error which I revived is

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

So what did I do wrong
Thanks

Comment: There is a comma missing in your list between second and third element.

Comment: Important note for the future: here the `TypeError` was produced on the `ls = ...` line, not on the `data = ...` line. This is important. Error messages try to be as descriptive as possible, to help you find the error in your code. The first thing an error message tells you is usually on which line the error was encountered. Don't dismiss that information.

Answer (score 3):

you've missed a `,` after the second array.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from such a detail that *dt* is a Datetime accessor in *Pandas*.
So it is "cleaner" when you use another name, e.g.:

```
from datetime import datetime as dtm
```

Then the only change to your source data is that I added a comma after
the second row:

```
ls = [
    [dtm(2021,  9,  4).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "WTM", 62, 100, 64, 100, 86, 100, 212, 300],
    [dtm(2021,  9,  5).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "WTA", 48,  60, 39,  60, 31,  60, 118, 180],
    [dtm(2021, 10, 23).strftime("%d-%m-%Y"), "WTM",  7, 100, 27, 100, 47, 100,  81, 300]]
```

Then I used your code and got proper result.

One more remark is that you should not use repeating column names.

Otherwise, after you have named columns just like you did,
when I run `data[['Max Marks']]` I get **all** 4 *Max Marks* columns.

Yet another hint is to use pandasonic *Timestamp* type, instead of *datetime*.
You can define your source data as:

```
ls = [
    [pd.Timestamp(2021,  9,  4), "WTM", 62, 100, 64, 100, 86, 100, 212, 300],
    [pd.Timestamp(2021,  9,  5), "WTA", 48,  60, 39,  60, 31,  60, 118, 180],
    [pd.Timestamp(2021, 10, 23), "WTM",  7, 100, 27, 100, 47, 100,  81, 300]]
```

Then the printout of the DataFrame looks just the same (*Exam Date*
printed in *yyyy-mm-dd* format).
And the true gain is that you can use date methods to select and/or
grouping of the source data.

Consider also using a MultiIndex on columns, creating the DataFrame as:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(ls, columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('Exam Date', ''),       ('Exam Type', ''),
    ('Maths',     'Result'), ('Maths',     'Max'),
    ('Chemistry', 'Result'), ('Chemistry', 'Max'),
    ('Physics',   'Result'), ('Physics',   'Max'),
    ('Total',     'Result'), ('Total',     'Max')]))
```

Then the DataFrame has "structural" column names. The first level is
the subject name and the second - either the *actual* or *Max* result:

```
   Exam Date Exam Type  Maths      Chemistry      Physics       Total     
                       Result  Max    Result  Max  Result  Max Result  Max
0 2021-09-04       WTM     62  100        64  100      86  100    212  300
1 2021-09-05       WTA     48   60        39   60      31   60    118  180
2 2021-10-23       WTM      7  100        27  100      47  100     81  300
```